# slf4j with glassfish is ignoring logback

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish, slf4j

In a java-ee maven project I have I'm wanting to use slf4j with logback, however I believe inclusion of the 'glassfish-embedded-all' artifact from org.glassfish.extras is causing the JDK14LoggerAdapter to be used instead.

Removing this artifact causes the logging to work as expected, however causes test failures due to java-ee api issues as described on this question - [Testing against Java EE 6 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424207/testing-against-java-ee-6-api).

The exact pom entry causing the problem, I believe, is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to configure slf4j to use logback? Or is there a better way of testing java ee code?

Answer (score 3):

The Glassfish Server includes an SLF4J Binding implementation which is also loaded.

If you open the glassfish jar with e.g. 7zip you see there is a org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class.

In my point of view they have implemented their own logging binder for JDK14Logging. Does anyone else know how to disable this Binding?

Also see this link: [logback with EJB3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418069/logback-with-ejb3-1/2454500#2419855)