# Logback configuration file is ignored

Tags: java, logback

The logback's configuration file is ignored into my WS module (I'm using glassfish).
The location .../src/main/resources/logback.xml

This is its content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
    ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

I start the WS service with the command mvn embedded-glassfish:run

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the logback libraries on the classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is. I find it into the WAR file at WEB-INF.classes location.

Comment: `logback.xml` is the last config file that logback looks for. Do you have any of [the other ones?](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: No, I haven't. I have only logback.xml

Comment: Silly question: have you confirmed that the logback.xml file is in the classpath after the build (the target/classes directory)?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is at ../target/classes/logback.xml

Comment: The same problem is reported here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474042/slf4j-with-glassfish-is-ignoring-logback

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was occurring because I was filtering out the logback.xml file in the maven build process.  I had to add an entry back in for the logback.xml file and then it worked:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>logback.xml</include>
                ...
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: this is perfect. in my case, we had a different default resources directory (was also dependent on maven profile), so when I added logback.xml just into /main/resources, it was actually ignored.